# How do I handle events with a TextFlow control?

Tags: java, javafx, textflow

I'm building a simple login registration form and I'm trying to use a text flow to switch the scene of the primary stage but for some reason, none of the event handlers I have attempted to use are working as intended

this is what i have tried so far

```
 TextFlow flow = new TextFlow(new Hyperlink("Dont have an account?"));
 flow.setOnMouseClicked(actionEvent -> primaryStage.setScene(scene2));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most controls in JavaFX consume mouse events by default<sup>1</sup>. That means when you click on the `Hyperlink` the event is consumed before it can bubble up to the `TextFlow`, thus your event handler is never invoked.

You should probably be setting the `onAction` property of the `Hyperlink` anyway, as that's not only more correct semantically but also allows reacting to keyboard input in addition to mouse input. For example:

```java
Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink("Don't have an account?");
link.setOnAction(e -> primaryStage.setScene(scene2));

TextFlow flow = new TextFlow(link);
// do something with 'flow'...
```

As an aside: Do you need to use `TextFlow` here? If all you're doing is placing a `Hyperlink` within the `TextFlow` then you should probably just be using the `Hyperlink` directly instead.

---

<sup>1. This is done by the `javafx.scene.control.SkinBase` class. See its `#consumeMouseEvents(boolean)` method.</sup>